# Is "took off" a phrasal verb?

Tags: phrasal-verbs, prepositional-phrases

> example: The airplane **took off** for Tokyo.

Is ‘took off’ a phrasal verb, and ‘for Tokyo’ an adjunct for the verb?

Comment: [Yes](http://www.usingenglish.com/reference/phrasal-verbs/take+off.html) Meaning: *When a plane departs or leaves the ground*

Comment: Note that *take off* is also a transitive phrasal verb with an entirely different meaning: *He took off his hat*.

Comment: @StoneyB, Thank you. I just now read that Bas Aarts suggest that they call the phrasal verb as “verb-preposition construction.” So in this case, “off’ is called “intransitive preposition.” : There may be no definite, absolute explanation. Your saying, “Context! Context!” is more reasonable than the theories.

Comment: The concept of *phrasal verbs* is a fairly recent invention, and Prof. Aarts is in this respect surprisingly conservative. It may be that the concept creates problems in some deeper theories of grammar; that's above my grade.  But I think that *phrasal verb* is (if nothing else) an excellent tool for teaching and learning English, and really reflects how speakers actually *use* these constructions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, *taking off* in an airplane is the verb used to describe when an airplane leaves the ground.  *Landing* is the opposite- when an airplane touches down on the ground again.

> [***take off***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/takeoff) : a rise or leap from a surface in making a jump or flight or an ascent in an aircraft or in the launching of a rocket

One of the running joke among pilots is the admonishment to make sure that the number of take-offs logged remains equal to the number of landings logged.

"*For Tokyo*" is the shortened version of *bound for Tokyo*- the airplane's destination was Tokyo.